# Syntax for inserting table into main query table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies for my (likely) misuse of wording, but I'm having some trouble with a query I'm writing.

Essentially I'm generating a table with one row per *shopper*, and one column for each *grocery item*, in which we find the percentage of their *visits* in which they purchased said *item*. I'm generating this table from a subquery, the output of which looks like:

```
Shopper | Visit | Butter | Milk | Eggs
Bill    |   A   |   1    |   0  |  1
Bill    |   B   |   0    |   1  |  1
John    |   C   |   0    |   1  |  0
John    |   D   |   1    |   1  |  1
```

As such, my main query displays the following:

```
Shopper | Butter % | Milk % | Eggs %
Bill    |    50%   |   50%  |  100%
John    |    50%   |   100% |   50%
```

I'm essentially dividing the sum of flags by sum of total visits, grouped by *shopper*.

However, I want to add one row at the bottom for percentages across all *shoppers*, so that my final table will be:

```
Shopper | Butter % | Milk % | Eggs %
Bill    |    50%   |   50%  |  100%
John    |    50%   |   100% |   50%
All     |    50%   |   75%  |   75%
```

My initial thought was to create a separate subquery for this, in which I mimic the logic to get the percentages (but leave the "group by" blank as to get percentages across all shoppers). I'm having some trouble appending *this* row to the bottom of my final table.

I did find the INSERT statement, and know there are a couple different ways to include it, but I'm not sure what that syntax would look like in the context of my main query.

There's probably a more straightforward way to explain this, but if my general format is

```
WITH <Subquery creation>,
     <Subquery 2 creation>
SELECT <create percent columns>
FROM <Subquery table>
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
```

I'm having trouble figuring out where such an INSERT statement would fit in.

It's also entirely possible there's an easier way to go about doing this, which I'm also open to. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try using WITH ROLLUP or WITH CUBE after the GROUP BY. That will tack on a totals row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use `grouping sets`.  In your `group by`, change:

```
group by shopper
```

to:

```
group by grouping sets ( (shopper), () )
```

This syntax is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for `group by`.

Comment: Interesting - this looks like it should do just the trick. Running now - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to `UNION` your result sets, since you have two working queries. You can stack CTEs with a comma between them.

```
WITH
  Subquery1 AS
  <logic>
, Subquery2 AS
  <logic>
SELECT * FROM Subquery1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Subquery2;
```